# Passing tint color between view controllers

Tags: objective-c

im trying to make a settings page that is able to change the global tint of the first view controller.

heres what i have (settings view controller & yes the colors arnt right yet):

```
-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{

if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"settingsSeque"]) {
    ViewController *tintColorChange = [segue destinationViewController];
    tintColorChange.view.tintColor = self.view.tintColor;

}



}


- (IBAction)tapRed:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)sender {
self.view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:0 blue:0 alpha:1];


}

- (IBAction)tapYellow:(UIButton *)sender {
self.view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.5 green:.3 blue:.1 alpha:1];
}

- (IBAction)tapGreen:(UIButton *)sender {
 self.view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:1 blue:0 alpha:1];
}

- (IBAction)tapBlue:(UIButton *)sender {
 self.view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0 green:0 blue:1 alpha:1];
}

- (IBAction)tapOrange:(UIButton *)sender {
self.view.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:.75 green:.5 blue:0 alpha:1];
}
```

And for the first view controller :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{



[super viewDidLoad];

self.view.tintColor = tintColorChange;
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: You should have a singleton that would handle all the colors, so in the settings page, all you needed to do was to apply the same color returned by the same method. Abstraction is good in this cases. All you would do in this class was changing its state.

Answer (score 1):

Create a delegate reference in your SettingsViewController:

```
@interface SettingsViewController ()
     @property (nonatomic) FirstViewController *delegateReference;
@end
```

Set FirstViewController instance to delegateReference:

```
settingsViewController.delegateReference = firstViewController;
```

Create a method in FirstViewController:

```
- (void)setBackgroundColor:(UIColor *)color {
    self.view.backgroundColor = color;
}
```

Now in your SettingsViewController button tap event call back:

```
- (IBAction)tapGreen:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (self.delegateReference) {
        [self.delegateReference setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    }
}
```

Also as Afonso Tsukamoto pointed out, it is good idea to put delegateReference in a singleton class.

Comment: ok im still having a problem with 

    settingsViewController.delegateReference = firstViewController;

says: unexpected interface name...

i know its probably something retarded im doing lol

Comment: also does anyone know a good place to learn about singltons? ive only been learning for about 2 months now.

Comment: In the context of this thread, "Singleton" is a class that gives you exact one instance regardless how many times you call it. There are many reference on the web, try Google "iOS Singleton".

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad
    {
    
    
    
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    settingsViewController.delegateReference = ViewController;

Comment: also i see 
   - (IBAction)tapGreen:(UIButton *)sender {
    if (self.delegateReference) {
        [self.delegateReference setBackgroundColor:[UIColor     greenColor]];
    }
}

im not trying to change the background, im trying to change the word colors. is this doing the same job?